# what does the operator ":\" do in this scala code?

Tags: scala

I just came across this on the scalacheck documentation and google was not very helpful in trying to lookup what the ":\" operator does:

```
abstract sealed class Tree[T] {
  def merge(t: Tree[T]) = Internal(List(this, t))

  def size: Int = this match {
    case Leaf(_) => 1
    case Internal(children) => (children :\ 0) (_.size + _)
  }
}

case class Internal[T](children: Seq[Tree[T]]) extends Tree[T]

case class Leaf[T](elem: T) extends Tree[T]
```

Also does anyone have any tips as to how to search for such funky symbols other than trawling through the nebulous scaladoc?

Thanks

Comment: You can use [Scalex](http://scalex.org/) to search for weird operators like that for Scala.

Comment: Yet another search engine oriented on such symbols is symbolhound.com

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's a foldRight.

```
(children :\ 0) (_.size + _)
```

is equivalent to

```
children.foldRight(0)(_.size + _)
```

and is also equivalent to

```
children.foldRight(0)((a,b) => a.size + b)
```

If you check the library code for Seq[T], the ':\' method is defined as:

```
def :\[B](z: B)(op: (A, B) => B): B = foldRight(z)(op)
```

Comment: not the first answer by two minutes but the most complete. any ideas how to get google, stackoverflow search, scaladoc search etc to pull up pages which document such operators. thanks!

Comment: This can be very hard to google. I'd recommend using a decent IDE like IntelliJ IDEA with Scala plugin or Scala IDE. Hit Ctrl-B or ⌘B (for IntelliJ IDEA) or F3 (for Scala IDE) at the method to jump to its definition. This feature is very helpful when learning a new library or framework. HTH.

Answer (score 2):

`:\` is alternate syntax for [`foldRight`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.Seq).

For searching for funky symbols you could use [Scalex](http://scalex.org/?q=%3A%5C+%2Bscala) or [sbt-man](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-man).

Comment: Thanks for sharing a good link for searching for functions thats a great help.

Answer (score 1):

It's alternate syntax for `foldRight`.

[scala-lang.org documentation](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.Iterator)